# Perl -- how to open / read / print -- directory and file content

Tags: html, perl

**QUESTION** (April 24, 2014):  I'm looking for a way to avoid manually revising a webpage to include links to files in a directory, in order to have the contents of those files displayed as code-snippets using Syntaxhighlighter.  Short of using a file-manager script (e.g., *.cgi or *.php), is there an easy way to evaluate files in a specific directory and include their content in a webpage?

In other words, I'd like to be able to manually add / delete / modify a code-snippet file from a directory and have the script evaluate the directory of snippets (anew) each time the wepage is loaded.  As it stands now, I would need to manually edit my webpage to change the name of `license.txt` if I renamed that file on the server.  I am hoping to simply specify a directory (e.g., `/home/lawlist/public_html/code_snippets`) and have the script evaluate the contents of that directory to populate the webpage with the contents of the files in that directory.  The behavior is similar to what a *.cgi or *.php file manager can do.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Judging from the [tag:javescript], I think you don't either.

Comment: @bjb568 -- Thank you for helping me to see that clarification of the question was needed.  I've revised the question to include some sample code and a better explanation of what is needed.  Another forum participant has graciously posted an answer, and I'll need to do some reading up on what was suggested.  Thanks again.  In the future, I'll need to remember that there are thousands of people who monitor the tags of `javascript` and `html`, and I'll make a better draft of my question before posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Perl Script** -- `test.cgi`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print <<HTML;

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>Document Title</title>

</head>

<body>

HTML

my $dir = '/home/lawlist/www';

my $query = new CGI;

my $name = $query->param('name');

my $file = $dir . "/" . $name;

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

  next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

  next unless ($file =~ m/\.txt|\.el$/);

  print '<a href="/cgi-bin/test.cgi?name=' . $file . '">' . $file . "</a>" . "<br>" . "\n\n"; }

closedir(DIR);

if ($name) {

  open (DATA, $file) or return $self->print_json_error($self->language('ERR_CANNOT_OPEN', $file->{name}, $!));

  read (DATA, my $file, -s DATA);

  close DATA;

  print '<pre class="brush:  lisp">' . "\n\n" . $file . "\n" . '</pre>'; }

print <<HTML;

</body>

</html>

HTML

exit 0;
```

**.htaccess Configuration**

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi

SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

# Customized server error messages:
# ErrorDocument 404 /page.not.found.basic.html

AddHandler cgi-script .pl .cgi
Options +Includes +ExecCGI

AddType text/html .shtml .shtm .html .htm
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .shtm .html .htm

# if you want to see the list of files in a directory
# without an index.html file, then uncomment the following line:

# Options +Indexes

Options -Indexes

# Options +FollowSymLinks

# Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
```

**Webpage Insert**:

```
<hr COLOR="#CCCCCC" size=1 NOSHADE>

<!--#exec cgi="/cgi-bin/test.cgi"-->

<hr COLOR="#CCCCCC" size=1 NOSHADE>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's server technology. In Server-Side JavaScript you can use nodejs' `fs` module and output the content.

"SyntaxHighlighting" is client-side technology, and you can use whatever library you like for code-coloring.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion -- I'll do some reading on that topic to familiarize myself with it -- greatly appreciated!